# Find an invertible matrix $S$ and a matrix $J$ in Jordan form, such that $S^{-1}AS = J$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

$A =  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        3 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

**We need to find an invertible matrix $S$ and a matrix in Jordan form $J$, such that $S^{-1}AS=J$.**

I've found that the characteristic polynomial is $P_A(\lambda) = \lambda^3(\lambda+1)$. Therefore, $\lambda = 0,-1$.

The minimal polynomial is $m_A(\lambda) = P_A(\lambda).$

At this stage, we know that $J = \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ (up to blocks' order).

**Next, I've found the Null Spaces:**

For $\lambda=0$:

$N(A) = N \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        3 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = span \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1
        \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$

$N(A^2) = N \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -3 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
        -7 & -1 & 4 & 1 \\
        2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = span \begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0
        \end{pmatrix},
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        \end{Bmatrix}$

$N(A^3) = N \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 1 & -2 & -1 \\
        3 & 1 & -2 & -1 \\
        9 & 3 & -6 & -3 \\
        3 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = span \begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0
        \end{pmatrix},
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 0
        \end{pmatrix},
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 3
        \end{pmatrix}
        \end{Bmatrix}$

For $\lambda=-1$:

$N(A+I) = N \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
        3 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = span \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ -1
        \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$

I'm not sure how to continue from here...

Comment: Do you know how to find Jordan basis?

Comment: At the point you identified $J$ you can just rewrite $J = S^{-1}AS$ to $SJ = AS$, $SJ-AS = 0$ and solve for $S$. It becomes a linear equation system if you vectorize $S$ and implement the matrix multiplications by $A$ and $J$ as Kronecker products. If unsolvable you got something wrong in identifying $J$ but you can still find a least squares solution.

Comment: @Itay4 Obviously I don't know. This is what I'm trying to figure out. I've looked online and found many explanations on the subject, but didn't really understand them.

Comment: Well, in order not to give you another explanation that won't understand, perhaps you could elaborate on what exactly you did not understand so we can explain.

Comment: @Itay4 We didn't learn how to use Kronecker products as mathreadler has mentioned, so I'm not sure how it works. I think it will be easier for me to understand by using the example I wrote, instead of a generalized and overly detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvector for $-1$ you already have, call it $v_1$. For $0$ what you want is a vector $v_4$ such that $A^3v_4 = 0$ but $A^2v_4 \ne 0$. I'll let you think of how to do this. (Incidentally all three vectors you have for a basis of $N(A^3)$ work.)

Once you have $v_4$, let $v_3 = Av_4$ and $v_2 = A^2v_4 = Av_3$. Then take

$$ S = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4). $$

Answer (score 2):

Once you have found $J$, finding $S$ is very easy. Just write $S=(s_{ij})$ and solve the linear equations in these coefficients given by the equation 
$$
AS=SJ.
$$
There are many solutions for $S$ here, and you have to pick one which satisfies $\det(S)\neq 0$.

Edit: Say, $S=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ with column vectors $x_1=(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)^T$ until $x_4=(s_{13},s_{14},s_{15},s_{16})^T$. Then
$AS=SJ$ is equivalent to $16$ easy equations
$$
s_1-s_2 = 0,\; s_6 =0, \; \cdots ,\; - s_{12} - s_{13} + s_{15} 
+ s_{16} = 0.
$$
This can be solved even by hand in a few minutes, e.g.,
$$
S=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \cr
3 & 2 & -2 & 1 \cr -1 & -1 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is what the Kronecker product would let us do systematically so we don't have to keep track of where everything ends up.

Comment: @Dietrich Isn't it tedious to solve by hand, or am I missing something? Can you please elaborate on how this solution will look like?

Comment: This is easy, if you use substitution of the variables (school mathematics). No Kronecker product, just matrix multiplication. And the matrices $A$ and $J$ only have coefficients $0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$, really easy. Of course, we get $16$ equations, but most of them are quite trivial. Can you solve linear equations with a computer, too?

Comment: I can, but not in a test.

Comment: All right, I did it by hand, see my edit. I think it is less computation than the other approach. I would prefer this in a test, but this is up to taste.